# HTML/CSS: flip3d how to do a 360 degrees with 4 pictures

Tags: html, css, 3d

I'm trying to make a mannequin spin at 360, however whenever I hover my mouse into it, the mannequin only spins "front" > "left" > "back" then the "right" is missing. Please help! I think I missed something here.

**CSS:**

```
.flip3D{ width:240px; height:200px; margin:10px; float:left; }

.flip3D > .front{
position: absolute;
transform: rotateY( 0deg );
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: transform 5s linear 1s; }
.flip3D > .left{
position: absolute;
transform: rotateY( 90deg );
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: transform 5s linear 1s; }
.flip3D > .back{
position: absolute;
transform: rotateY( 180deg );
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: transform 5s linear 1s; }
.flip3D > .right{
position: absolute;
transform: rotateY( 270deg );
backface-visibility: hidden;
transition: transform 5s linear 1s; }


.flip3D:hover > .front{
transform: rotateY( -180deg );
}
.flip3D:hover > .left{
transform: rotateY( -90deg );
}
.flip3D:hover > .back{
transform: rotateY( 0deg );
}
.flip3D:hover > .right{
transform: rotateY( 90deg );
}
```

Thanks by the way! :)

**EDIT:**

Here's the **HTML**:

```
<div class="flip3D">
<div class="front"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/B7sC8PO.png"></div>
<div class="left"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/WBL420n.png"></div>
<div class="back"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/iP4o59F.png"></div>
<div class="right"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/9TDxCLU.png"></div>
< /div>
```

Comment: can you make fiddle or provide html structure ?

Comment: This is the only html structure I made:

<div class="flip3D">
 <div class="front"><img src="front.png"></div>
 <div class="left"><img src="left.png"></div>
 <div class="back"><img src="back.png"></div>
 <div class="right"><img src="right.png"></div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: @DorineMae Without the images, it's super hard to help you. Can you provide a link to the mannequin images?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I'll upload it.

Comment: Extra div at end? please remove that extra div at end..thank you

Comment: Oops, silly. Thanks.

Comment: Any luck, @Dorine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little wonky, but I think this is the right idea. [Demo](http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/GZGOwK).

For the demo, I just have the container continuously spinning. You could pretty easily adjust it to work on hover. Instead of rotating each individual side on hover of the container, I just pre-rotate them . Then, I apply the 360 spin to the container itself, so each side is shown during the 5 second spin revolution.

```
@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotateY(0); }
  to { transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
}

.flip3D { 
  width:240px; 
  height:200px; 
  margin:10px auto; 
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
}

.flip3D > div {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip3D > .front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip3D > .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip3D > .right {
  transform: rotateY(-270deg);
}

.flip3D > .left {
  transform: rotateY(270deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it :)

Answer (score 1):

so thank you so much for all your suggestions and answers. So instead of hovering my mouse to the image to rotate it, this is what I came to:

**SCRIPT:**

```
varSide = 0
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = varSide; 

function myFunctionLeft(id1,id2,id3,id4) {
    var a = document.getElementById(id1);
    var b = document.getElementById(id2);
    var c = document.getElementById(id3);
    var d = document.getElementById(id4);

        if (varSide==0){
        varSide = -1;
        a.style.display = 'block';
        b.style.display = 'none';
        c.style.display = 'none';
        d.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (varSide==-1){
        varSide = 2;
        a.style.display = 'none';
        b.style.display = 'none';
        c.style.display = 'none';
        d.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if (varSide==2){
        varSide = 1;
        a.style.display = 'none';
        b.style.display = 'none';
        c.style.display = 'block';
        d.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{
        varSide = 0;
        a.style.display = 'none';
        b.style.display = 'block';
        c.style.display = 'none';
        d.style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = varSide; 
}   

function myFunctionRight(id1,id2,id3,id4) {
    var a = document.getElementById(id1);
    var b = document.getElementById(id2);
    var c = document.getElementById(id3);
    var d = document.getElementById(id4);

        if (varSide==0){
        varSide = 1;
        a.style.display = 'none';
        b.style.display = 'none';
        c.style.display = 'block';
        d.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (varSide==1){
        varSide = 2;
        a.style.display = 'none';
        b.style.display = 'none';
        c.style.display = 'none';
        d.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if (varSide==2){
        varSide = -1;
        a.style.display = 'block';
        b.style.display = 'none';
        c.style.display = 'none';
        d.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{
        varSide = 0;
        a.style.display = 'none';
        b.style.display = 'block';
        c.style.display = 'none';
        d.style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = varSide; 
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="myFunctionLeft('id1','id2','id3','id4');">
<button onclick="myFunctionLeft('id1','id2','id3','id4')" type="btnLeft">Left!</button>
<button onclick="myFunctionRight('id1','id2','id3','id4')" type="btnRight">Right!</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<div id="id1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/B7sC8PO.png"></div>
<div id="id2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/9TDxCLU.png"></div>
<div id="id3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/iP4o59F.png"></div>
<div id="id4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/WBL420n.png"></div>
```